# Hyperledger Fabric, byfn.sh returns Permission Denied right after start

Tags: permissions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, cat

I am following the tutorial on  [how to build my first network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html) and have downloaded all the libraries and binaries that the documentations provide. I generate the network however when I run the byfn.sh up command, I get the START print out and immidietely after a cat: log.txt: Permission denied fail and an error test failed. I have tried running it with sudo, going to the root with sudo -i, nothing works and I keep getting this error. Please help.

```html
<pre>Starting for channel &apos;mychannel&apos; with CLI timeout of &apos;10&apos; seconds and CLI delay of &apos;3&apos; seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.3
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.3
Starting peer1.org2.example.com ... <font color="#4E9A06">done</font>
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... <font color="#4E9A06">done</font>
Starting peer0.org2.example.com ... <font color="#4E9A06">done</font>
Starting orderer.example.com    ... <font color="#4E9A06">done</font>
Starting peer1.org1.example.com ... <font color="#4E9A06">done</font>
cli is up-to-date
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                              PORTS                    NAMES
e17f63f2cb6c        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     &quot;/bin/bash&quot;         2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                 cli
7b7b2971b426        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      &quot;peer node start&quot;   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) Less than a second ago                            peer1.org2.example.com
6ab313507396        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      &quot;peer node start&quot;   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 1 second ago                                      peer0.org2.example.com
510f5fc13622        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   &quot;orderer&quot;           2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 1 second ago                                      orderer.example.com
6e5a09bacbeb        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      &quot;peer node start&quot;   2 minutes ago       Up Less than a second               0.0.0.0:7051-&gt;7051/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
5e36c3878301        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      &quot;peer node start&quot;   2 minutes ago       Up Less than a second               0.0.0.0:8051-&gt;8051/tcp   peer1.org1.example.com
28cebd0e310f        hello-world                         &quot;/hello&quot;            4 minutes ago       Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                                     admiring_driscoll
d04613d6be54        hello-world                         &quot;/hello&quot;            6 minutes ago       Exited (0) 6 minutes ago                                     keen_swanson
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

 ____    _____      _      ____    _____ 
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ &lt;    | |  
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
+ res=1
+ set +x
cat: log.txt: Permission denied
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with Docker permission. I reinstalled docker and followed the after installation steps from the docker page and now it works.